# Diskless Booting - grub.cfg & NFS

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, nfs, pxe

I have used guide:-https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64 to build PXE server and currently it is working.

I plan to build upon this and make an environment where diskless client is possible.

Steps done as of yet:-

1. Setup a Client (installed ISO, file, software etc. ) to copy the root filesystem from here.
2. Copied the root file system to NFS server.

At the moment I am having problem passing this rootfs in grub.cfg as I don't really understand where (initrd/kernel) should I pass the parameter against ? Also do I have to change the initrd as this is just the initrd I got from the Ubuntu ISO.

My current grub.cfg :-

```
    set default="0" set timeout=-1
    
    if loadfont unicode ; then   set gfxmode=auto   set locale_dir=$prefix/locale   set lang=en_US fi terminal_output gfxterm
    
    set menu_color_normal=white/black set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray if background_color 44,0,30; then   clear fi
    
    function gfxmode {   set gfxpayload="${1}"   if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7   else
        set vt_handoff=   fi }
    
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    
    export linux_gfx_mode
    
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 22.04' {   
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode   #linux /distros/ubuntu22.04/vmlinuz $vt_handoff quiet splash   
#linux /distros/ubuntu22.04/vmlinuz url=http://192.168.0.134/iso/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso only-ubiquity ip=dhcp ---   
linux /distros/ubuntu22.04/vmlinuz
    
      initrd /distros/ubuntu22.04/initrd 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and here it is for anyone trying to do the same.

[image: Solution]

You also have to change initrd. Please follow [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto).